# Accessing a Powershell Mounted Drive in R

Tags: r, powershell, networking, nas

So I have a Powershell script that I would like to execute on a small cluster and the core of that script is an R script. In Powershell I mount a drive with:

```
New-PSDrive –Name Q: –PSProvider FileSystem –Root \\this-isa-addr01\subdrive
```

and I can access the Q: drive in the Powershell terminal. But the next step is to run an R script that does the following:

```
load("Q:/thisIsAWorkspaceWithABunchOfPrecomputedStuffAndDataInIt")
```

However, R can't find the file or for that matter the drive. I tried running

```
ls("Q:")
```

to no avail. I get the error:

```
Error in as.environment(pos) :  No item called "Q:" on the search list
```

I also have tried to do

```
ls("\\\\this-isa-addr01/subdrive")
```

but that gives me the same error.

Do I need to pass some environment variable from powershell to R? Is there a better way to load data from an unmounted drive?

**EDIT:** Additional question, is it possible to mount a NAS drive in R? That's really what I want to do it doesn't have to be in Powershell.

**EDIT:** I have tried using -Persist as well. I get a cannot find parameter message. When I run Get-Help New-PSDrive this is the output which does not mention Persist.

```
  DESCRIPTION
  The New-PSDrive cmdlet creates a Windows PowerShell drive that is "mapped" to or associated with a location in a data store, such as a network drive, a directory on the local computer, or a registry key.

You can use the Windows PowerShell drives that you create to access data in the associated data store, just like you would do with any mapped drive. You can change locations into the drive (using "set-location", "cd", or "chdir") and access the contents of the drive (using "get-item", "get-childitem", or "dir").

However, the Windows PowerShell drives are known only to Windows PowerShell. You cannot access them by using Windows Explorer, Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), Component Object Model (COM), or the Microsoft .NET Framework, or by using tools such as Net Use.

Windows PowerShell drives exist only in the current Windows PowerShell session. To make the drive persistent, you can export the session to which you have added the drive, or you can save a New-PSDrive command in your Windows PowerShell profile.

To delete a drive that was created by New-PSDrive, use the Remove-PSDrive cmdlet.
```

Comment: PowerShell provider drives exist only for PowerShell itself. Pass some path (not drive) to R somehow, env. variable is an option, yes.

Comment: Ok. What about cmd.exe? Can I mount the drive globally in cmd.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Get-Help New-PSDrive` :

```
Mapped network drives: You can use the Persist parameter of New-PSDrive to 
create Windows mapped network drives. Unlike temporary Windows PowerShell 
drives, Windows mapped network drives are not session-specific; they are 
saved in Windows and they can be managed by using standard Windows tools, 
such as File Explorer and Net Use. Mapped network drives must have a 
drive-letter name and be connected to a remote file system
location.
```

If you want to mount a drive so that other apps, even powershell sessions can see it, use `-Persist`.

Note: If you are stuck on Powershell v2, you will have to resort to using `net use DRIVELETTER PATH`

Comment: Persist doesn't exist in my version I don't think. Updating the question with more info.

Comment: You should be able to shell out to cmd and run the net use command. See the final Note in my answer

Comment: Ah yes, it appears I am stuck on Powershell v2. Thank you for your help Eris!